# Order of column in R

Tags: r

I want to get the number in order of the column in a dataframe.

```
df <- data.frame(item = rep(c('a','b','c'), 3),
             year = rep(c('2010','2011','2012'), each=3),
             count = c(1,4,6,3,8,3,5,7,9))
```

Lets say the function i am looking for is columnorder. I want to have this result

```
x <- columnorder(df$count)
x
> 3

x <- columnorder(df$item)
x
> 1
```

It seems like a basic task but I couldn't find the answer until now. I will appreciate your help. Thank you

Comment: this does the job `which(colnames(df) == "count")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said,

> It seems like a basic task but I couldn't find the answer until now.

In the general sense what you are trying to do -- translate a column name into a column index -- *is* basic, and a pretty common question. However, the particular scenario you describe above, where your input is of the form `object_name$column_name`, is atypical WRT what you are trying to achieve, which is most likely why you haven't found an existing solution.

In short, the problem is that when you pass an argument as `df$count`, you may as well just have used `c(1,4,6,3,8,3,5,7,9)` instead, because `df$count` will be evaluated as `c(1,4,6,3,8,3,5,7,9)`. Of course, R does allow for a fair bit of metaprogramming, so with a little extra work, this *could* be implemented as, for example

```
column_order <- function(expr) {
    x <- strsplit(deparse(substitute(expr)), "$", TRUE)[[1]]
    match(x[2], names(get(x[1])))
}

column_order(df$item)
#[1] 1
column_order(df$year)
#[1] 2
column_order(df$count)
#[1] 3
```

But as I said above, this is an atypical interface for what you are ultimately trying to do. A much more standard approach would be for this function to accept the column name (typically as a string) and the target object as arguments, in which case the solution is much simpler:

```
column_order2 <- function(col, obj) match(col, names(obj))

column_order2("item", df)
#[1] 1
column_order2("year", df)
#[1] 2
column_order2("count", df)
#[1] 3
```

Comment: Thank you @nrussell for your detailed answer. My R world is extended again :)

Answer (score 1):

As proposed in the comments by @mtoto, here is one solution:

```
x <- which(colnames(df) == "count")
```

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, I forgot to look in the comments section.

Comment: Thank you @mtoto and snoram, I like the way your solution is quick and simple